# customize bluetooth enabled dialog msg

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

The Android doc states that if I need to enable Bluetooth programmatically then I have to show dialog using its provided intent to ask the user. I am wondering is there a way to customize the message shown ? I wan to tell the user why I am enabling the bluetooth when  I ask them for confirmation

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

According to Android docs, you could use mBluetoothAdapter.enable(). If you add the proper permissions in the manifest ( BLUETOOTH_ADMIN ), you should be able to turn on the bluetooth adapter.

The docs say that you should never call this method without user consent, so you should create a custom dialog and enable the bluetooth only if the user says yes.

It also says that you should listen for ACTION_STATE_CHANGED to know when the device is actually on.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#enable()